# How to create app pool and virtual directory for IIS in Powershell

Tags: powershell, iis, iis-7, application-pool

I'm trying to create a powershell script for creating application pools and virtual directories using IIS 7 or 8 (not sure which one I have, I'm using Windows Server 2012 R2)

Anyway here is the code I'm using to create an app pool called .Net v2.0

```
Import-Module WebAdministration 
New-Item –Path IIS:\AppPools\.Net v2.0
```

But I'm getting an error stating

> PS IIS:\Sites> Import-Module WebAdministration  New-Item –Path
>   IIS:\AppPools.Net v2.0 Undefined object type .Net. Parameter name:
>   nodeName At line:2 char:1
>   + New-Item –Path IIS:\AppPools.Net v2.0
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], ArgumentException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NewItemDynamicParametersProviderException

I feel like it might be because of the space in between Net and v2.0

Also there is no physical path for this so I'm not sure how to create a script for multiple app pools all in one, some are using v2.0 and v4.0 and some are using Integrated and Classic for the pipeline and some are using physical paths where as some don't. If someone could point me in the right direction? I'm not using websites just app pools and virtual directories.

Thanks!

**EDIT**
I was able to fix this problem by using

```
[system.reflection.assembly]::Loadwithpartialname("Microsoft.Web.Administration")
$servermgr = New-Object Microsoft.web.administration.servermanager
$servermgr.ApplicationPools.Add(".NETExample")
$servermgr.CommitChanges()
```

Comment: Try it in quotes `New-Item –Path 'IIS:\AppPools\.Net v2.0'`  PowerShell will assume parameter values are strings so you can often get away without quotes for convenience, but if there has to be a space in it, use quotes.

Comment: Thank you, I actually got it working with a different code. I went ahead and posted the solution above under **EDIT**.

Answer (score 1):

Run first `Import-Module WebAdministration` that will allow you to create the Path under IIS:\

Then:

```
$iisAppPoolName = ".Net v2.0"
$iisAppPoolDotNetVersion = "v2.0"
$iisAppName = "Net 2"
$directoryPath = "E:\Net2"

cd IIS:\AppPools\

New-Item $iisAppPoolName
```

Check this site: [Create IIS App Pool](http://geekswithblogs.net/QuandaryPhase/archive/2013/02/24/create-iis-app-pool-and-site-with-windows-powershell.aspx)

Comment: When I run it I get this error 

Undefined object type .Net v2.0.
Parameter name: nodeName
At line:9 char:1
+ New-Item $iisAppPoolName
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NewItemDynamicParametersProviderException

Comment: Let´s try the following:

First import the module:

`Import-Module WebAdministration`

Then, 

`Get-ChildItem IIS:\Sites` and paste the output.

Comment: PS IIS:\Sites\> Get-ChildItem IIS:\Sites

Name             ID   State      Physical Path                  Bindings

Comment: ----             --   -----      -------------                  --------                                                                                     
Default Web Site 1    Started    %SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot  http *:80:                                                                                   
                                                                https *:443: sslFlags=0                                                                      
net 2            2               E:\Net2

Comment: PS IIS:\Sites\> New-WebAppPool -Name ".Net v2.0"

Comment: Thank you, I actually got it working with a different code. I went ahead and posted the solution above under **EDIT**.